# Lifetime in impl does not match method in trait

Tags: rust, lifetime

## Code

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6eeb0140ad49f1e5c99861473bf9f57e) (Stable Rust 1.45.0, 2018 edition) No external crates needed for example.

```
type Error = Box<dyn std::error::Error>;
type Result<R=()> = std::result::Result<R, Error>;

struct Arena;

pub trait AsSized<'a> {
    type AsSized: Sized + 'a;
}
impl<'a, T: Sized + 'a> AsSized<'a> for T {
    type AsSized = Self;
}
impl<'a, T: AsSized<'a>> AsSized<'a> for [T] {
    type AsSized = &'a [T::AsSized];
}

pub trait Format<T>: Send + Sync
where T: ?Sized
{
    fn get_bytes<'a>(&self, value: &'a T, arena: &'a Arena) -> Result<&'a [u8]>;
    fn get_value<'a>(&self, bytes: &'a [u8], arena: &'a Arena) -> Result<T::AsSized>
    where T: AsSized<'a>;
}

struct RawBytes;

impl Format<[u8]> for RawBytes
where [u8]: for<'a> AsSized<'a, AsSized=&'a [u8]>
{
    fn get_bytes<'a>(&self, value: &'a [u8], _arena: &'a Arena) -> Result<&'a [u8]> {
        Ok(value)
    }
    fn get_value<'a>(&self, bytes: &'a [u8], arena: &'a Arena) -> Result<<[u8] as AsSized<'a>>::AsSized> {
        Ok(bytes)
    }
}
```

## Issue

I'm getting a compiler error on the impl of `get_value` for `RawBytes`:

```
error[E0195]: lifetime parameters or bounds on method `get_value` do not match the trait declaration
```

I don't understand what the problem is. It seems like the lifetime specification is the same between both definitions. How do I write the impl of `get_value` for `RawBytes` so that it works?

I would think that since `u8: Sized` then `<u8 as AsSized<'a>>::AsSized = u8` and then `<[u8] as AsSized<'a>>::AsSized = &'a [u8]` but it seems like that isn't the case?

## Background

`Format` takes an arena based allocator and converts a slice of bytes to and from a complex type. I plan to write an adapter for various Serde formats. `RawBytes` is a trivial implementaiton of `Format` for a slice of bytes that just returns the original slice.

Both methods of `Format` are allowed to return a value that borrows from the input value. The format itself may be shared between threads, so the lifetime of self is unrelated to the returned value.

The purpose of `AsSized` is to allow dynamically sized types like `str` and `[u8]` to be used directly, but since dynamically sized types can't be returned directly, `AsSized` provides a sized equivalent for any type; dynamically sized types return a reference to the DST instead  (borrowed from the arena). Sized types like `u8` that can be returned directly have an `AsSized` type of self

## Also tried

```
fn get_value<'a>(&self, bytes: &'a [u8], arena: &'a Arena) -> Result<'a [u8]>
```

I tried simplifying the impl's `get_value` to just name the slice directly; rust then says that the impl for `get_value` is missing entirely.

```
fn get_value<'a>(&self, bytes: &'a [u8], arena: &'a Arena) -> Result<&'a [<u8 as AsSized<'a>>::AsSized]>
```

This give the same "lifetime parameters... do not match" error.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. In the future, try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then edit your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) tips you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I didn't know there was a guide for this, should have checked the tag. I will edit the question.

Comment: I added a playground link that reproduces the exact same error I am getting and added a note about the version of Rust I am using.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer (i got stuck too :)

---

I kept deleting code until I reached this minimal example that reproduces the error:

```rust
pub trait AsSized<'a> {
    type AsSized: Sized + 'a;
}

pub trait Format<T>
where
    T: ?Sized,
{
    fn get_value<'a>(&self, bytes: &'a [u8])
    where
        T: AsSized<'a>;
}

impl Format<[u8]> for () {
    fn get_value<'a>(&self, bytes: &'a [u8]) {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

It now becomes apparent that, in the trait definition, there is a further constraint on the `'a` lifetime: we require that `T: AsSized<'a>`, and this is what's causing the error. You don't have such a clause on the `impl` block, hence the compiler doesn't accept the lifetimes as equivalent.

(I'm not sure if they're actually incompatible or if this is a limitation of the compiler)

So I decided to add `where [u8]: AsSized<'a>` to the `impl` function as well. To get it to compile, I also:

- Made `Arena` public (type leak issue)
- Removed `where [u8]: for<'a> AsSized<'a, AsSized=&'a [u8]>` from the `impl` (this where clause makes no sense to me – it seems it has no point since it doesn't involve a generic? i could be wrong. anyway it was causing a weird error)
- Replaced the function body with `todo!()`

So this compiles:

```rust
fn main() {}

type Error = Box<dyn std::error::Error>;
type Result<R = ()> = std::result::Result<R, Error>;

pub struct Arena;

pub trait AsSized<'a> {
    type AsSized: Sized + 'a;
}
impl<'a, T: Sized + 'a> AsSized<'a> for T {
    type AsSized = Self;
}
impl<'a, T: AsSized<'a>> AsSized<'a> for [T] {
    type AsSized = &'a [T::AsSized];
}

pub trait Format<T>: Send + Sync
where
    T: ?Sized,
{
    fn get_bytes<'a>(&self, value: &'a T, arena: &'a Arena) -> Result<&'a [u8]>;
    fn get_value<'a>(&self, bytes: &'a [u8], arena: &'a Arena) -> Result<T::AsSized>
    where
        T: AsSized<'a>;
}

struct RawBytes;

impl Format<[u8]> for RawBytes {
    fn get_bytes<'a>(&self, value: &'a [u8], _arena: &'a Arena) -> Result<&'a [u8]> {
        Ok(value)
    }
    fn get_value<'a>(
        &self,
        bytes: &'a [u8],
        arena: &'a Arena,
    ) -> Result<<[u8] as AsSized<'a>>::AsSized>
    where
        [u8]: AsSized<'a>,
    {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, as soon as I replace the `todo!()` back with your `Ok(bytes)`, it breaks again. The compiler apparently doesn't know that `<[u8] as AsSized<'a>>::AsSized` is the same as `&'a [u8]`. Oh well.

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:42:12
   |
42 |         Ok(bytes)
   |         -- ^^^^^ expected associated type, found `&[u8]`
   |         |
   |         arguments to this enum variant are incorrect
   |
   = note: expected associated type `<[u8] as AsSized<'a>>::AsSized`
                    found reference `&'a [u8]`
   = help: consider constraining the associated type `<[u8] as AsSized<'a>>::AsSized` to `&'a [u8]` or calling a method that returns `<[u8] as AsSized<'a>>::AsSized`
   = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html
```